# RabbitMQ: how to handle unwanted duplicate un-ack message after connection lost?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

In my app(multiple instances), we occasionally see the case where connection is lost between my app and rabbitmq due to network issues(my app and rabbitmq are both alive), then after connection is recovered(re-established) we will receive messages that are unacked.

This creates an issue for us, because my app wasn't dead, and it is still processing the same message it received before, but now the message is redeivered, and it causes the app to process the message again (which can be fatal to us).

Since the app has multiple instances, it is not easy for an instance to check if another instance is processing the same message at the same time. **We can't simply filter out redelivered message, because we need this feature to handle instance/app crashes/re-deployments.**

It doesn't seem that there is an api to tell rabbitmq when to not redeliver unacked messages.

So what is the recommended practice to handle this situation ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The general solution for such scenario is to make the consumers handle the messages in an idempotent manner . Generally what I do is from the producer side ( in case there is no unique identifier in the message body ) I add an attribute **idempotencyId** to the message body which is a guid and on the consumer side for each message this id is validated against the stored value in database , any duplicates are rejected.

This approach also works for messages which might be shoveled from another cluster or if in a same cluster multiple instances of consumers are listening then too this approach guarantee one time processing.

Would suggest to go over the RabbitMQ Reliability Guide [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html)

Comment: Id the sending application is also uses spring-rabbit, the `AbstractMessageConverter` has a property `createMessageIds` (false by default). If you set it to `true`, the framework will insert a UUID into the `message_id` message property.

Comment: The problem is that we can't simply reject a duplicate message. As stated in the question, in cases like recover from app cash or in-service redeployment, my app does rely on this redelivered message to re-reprocess the message. It just we can't differentiate why the message was redelivered to avoid having multiple app instances processing the same message at the same time.

Comment: Obviously the Broker will not wait for anyone to request for undelivered messages  it is a queue so anything that is acknowledged is removed and anything that is un-acknowledged remains in queue and is re delivery attempt is made on subsequent consumer connection...

Comment: yes, i understand that, which is why i was also wondering if there is an option to tell the broker I am still the same old connection with some sort of UUID as identity, so rabbitmq won't redeliver when the connection is recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, *exactly-once* delivery is not something RabbitMQ is good at. In fact, I'd say you should probably not be using it for these kinds of problems. Honestly, the only way to truly fix this is to use distributed transactions or locking.

Anyway, you could turn the problem on its head by ack'ing the message as soon as the consumer gets it, before it starts working on it. That would avoid the RabbitMQ-related duplication issue at least. This is *at-most-once* delivery.

Of course, it means that if the consumer crashes, the message is lost forever. So you need to persist the message right before you ack it so you can recover it later and also the consumer should remove it once it's complete.

Considering that crashes are rare, you can then have a single dedicated process that just works on those persisted messages. Or for that matter, handle them manually.

Just be aware that you are pushing the duplication problem in front of you, because the consumer might fail to remove the persisted message after it's done working with it anyway, but at least you have the option to implement it however you want.

Storage in this case could be anything from files, a RDBMS or something like ZooKeeper or Redis to lock/unlock in-flight messages.

Comment: Thanks, "crashes" are not very rare from what we observed in cloud environment (sometimes it is not crash, it is simply container being shutdown), and also app updates/redeployments are regular. Some of message processing duration is expected to be long, so a locking/unlocking in-flight message can be problematic too in these cases.

Comment: @wei yeah well, rare in the sense that 99.999...% of messages are not affected by these restarts. At least I’m hoping that’s the case anyway.